# RTL Word in sidemenu ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I just want to flip the word inside side menu to right, my sidemenu is to the right but the word still using LTR even i apply on the rtl on the theme folder

in the variables.scss

```
$app-direction: rtl;
```

on cal.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color = "newcolor">
      <button ion-button menuToggle right>
          <ion-icon name="menu" style="text-align:right"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-title style="text-align:right">ألـة الحاسبـة</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also write `@include rtl()` in selector for flip right to left and for left to right `@include ltr()` function used .Below i have give example adding `page-title` class to `@include rtl()` function to flip right to left

cal.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color = "newcolor">
      <button ion-button menuToggle right>
          <ion-icon name="menu" class="page-icon"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-title class="page-title">ألـة الحاسبـة</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

variables.scss

```
 $app-direction: rtl;

   .page-title  {
         @include rtl {
                // Custom rtl style goes here
                text-align:right
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is showing error on .scss  " no mixin named rtl Backtrace: src/theme/variables.scss:15"

Comment: remove function from rtl() write only rlt see at edited code

Answer (score 0):

Fixed title direction

```
<ion-title dir="rtl">ألـة الحاسبـة</ion-title>
```